# Swift: Stop a Method From Completing

Tags: ios, swift

Users search for cities based on name in my app after which I make multiple API calls from different sources to get information on the cities.

I want to add a Stop button so that a user can stop the search if, for example, they have a bad wifi connection and the search is taking too long. I have my API calls in different methods, so I won't know which one is running when the user clicks the Stop button.

Is anyone familiar with a way to stop all functions or even just the API calls running in the app when the user clicks Stop?

I've included my proposed solution below, but would like to know if anyone has a more elegant solution.

Comment: Basically it seems to me you are describing NSOperation. I would suggest you look into that instead of reinventing the wheel. By moving your entire operation into its own class, you allow _each_ operation to be cancellable separately, without the confusion of your proposed timestamps.

Comment: @matt thanks, I'm not familiar with NSOperation. Any good references you recommend that I should take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

My proposed solution is to have two variables that store timestamps, a permanent variable and another created in the action method that is called when the user clicks Search. It would work as follows:

- The user clicks Search
- A permanent variable is saved with the exact time of the search: 2017_02_16_4:35:26 (date and time to seconds), the variable created in the action method is made to match the permanent variable
- Once the API calls are complete, but before the segue to show the new information is triggered, I'll check to make sure both variables are still in sync
- If a user clicks the stop button, I'll change the permanent variable to the time the Stop button was clicked, and the segue won't execute because the two variables won't match.

  ```
  var permanentTimestamp = String()

  @IBAction func searchButton(_ sender: Any) {
       permanentTimestamp = // whatever the current time is
       self.beginAPICalls()
  }

  func beginAPICalls() {
       let uniqueCallTimestamp = permanentTimestamp

       //... perform API calls and get information

       if uniqueCallTimestamp == permanentTimestamp {
            // perform segue
       } else {
            // the segue won't be triggered and the user can search again without having two searches go through
       }
  }
  ```

I'd considered just using boolean values, but a potential issue would be if a user has internet connection but it is very slow. The user could search (bool = true), click Stop (bool = false), and then click Search again (bool = true) before the first set of API calls had completed. Now the bool is true allowing the segue to happen, but both calls will be made.